# Is there a "Lockdown" profile in iOS?

Tags: security, ios, enterprise, security-policy

I've been trying to discover if it's possible to create a profile for an iOS device that will prevent the user from installing apps. So far I've not been able to find anything. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such function (at least, on non-jailbroken iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions doesn't work? Settings>General>Restrictions and then set Installing Apps to OFF